# How to print a json object array

Tags: jquery, xml, arrays, json, youtube

I found a jquery function online that i then tweaked a little, but it takes a youtube channels feed data and turns it into a json object. It then stores data from the objects arrays. I need to store extra data that IS given, but I dont know how to display the data so I can see the data in its arrays. Im sure this sounds confusing and that is because I dont know about json objects or how to print out the data in jquery. Ive done it before in php with the print function I believe.

This is the function mentioned:

```
$j(function() {
    $j.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/iCallOfDutyFILMS/uploads?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=?&max-results=1', function(data) {
        $j.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
            var updated = item.updated;
            var url = item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url'];
            var thumb = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
            var numViews = item['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];
            //var vidDescription = item[''][''];
            var width = 710; //only change this number
            var height = width*9/16;
            //...rest left out...

        });
    });
});
```

I want to print out the array to see how to grab the video description. I just dont know the path to it through the array. Is there a way in jquery to print out the arrays similar to how I was able to in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome or Firefox, Press `F12`, This will bring up the Inspector. Click on 'Console' to show the console window.

Now in your javascript code, whatever variable or object you want to print or 'inspect'. Pass it into the console log method.

```
var your_array_variable = "a string variable";  
console.log(your_array_variable); //<-- This is what you want to do!
```

Now refresh the page and run the event or function that you are building.

Voila!... In your console window you should see `>Object` (If you print a Object).

Or in the example above.. You would see `a string variable` in the console.

Click on the expand tree node, (`>`) to view the object/variables details.

You can console.log almost anything!.. Its a great way to learn whats going on.

You can also set 'breakpoints', but this is a whole other question!..

**I think what your looking for is:**

`console.log(data); // To show the JSON data received`

---

**Update**
Try this, It worked for me, in console you will see 2 objects you can click on and inspect. The first is the data from the json request, the second is the item looped in the $.each.
This worked for me, On click of anything with the `id="get_json"`. This will make the request, and log the response to the console.

```
    $('#get_json').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(function() {
            var json_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/iCallOfDutyFILMS/uploads?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&max-results=1&callback=?';
            $.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
                console.log(data); // Here we log to our console
                $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
                    console.log(item); // This is what you want i think
                    var updated = item.updated;
                    var url = item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url'];
                    var thumb = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
                    var numViews = item['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];
                    //var vidDescription = item[''][''];
                    var width = 710; //only change this number
                    var height = width*9/16;
                    //...rest left out...

                });
            }).success(function() { alert("success"); })
            // Errors are your friend!.. Use them..
              .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("error " + textStatus);
                        console.log("error throw " + errorThrown);
                        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }) // End of .error
              .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
            });
        });
```

Comment: After my page loads, i type console.log(data); and it says 'data is not defined'. But it says in the code i posted above that data IS where object is stored. Then i type in var data = "hey";
console.log(data); Just to test it and it prints out 'hey'. Im lost at why in your example i should declare a new variable when it should be already created by my jquery/js code? I thought it would have been declared already. help?

Comment: isnt the scope of data only within the start and end of that function? or is it not that same as system languages and the variable still exists?

Comment: Hi, I updated my post, try it out, it worked 100% for me, it logs the data and item to the console and you can inspect them by clicking on them.

Comment: Have no idea what you did, but i understand now that i was supposed to put console.log(data or item) into my JS code, which was a part i was missing.

Comment: Anyways this worked great and thanks so much for the help :D made my day right now

Answer (score 3):

If you use Firebug or other developer tools, you can console.log(data) and then inspect the JSON response in Firebug (or whatever inspection tool you're using). Then you can use that view to determine the "path" to access the video description that you want.

Good luck.

Comment: when i was searching around on the net and i did see using the console as a remedy to my situation, but i have no idea how to use the console. I use firebug. what would i type in the console to get said results? the array is called 'item' i believe. I did try console.log(item); and it says item is not defined. :/

Comment: In your case, you want to do console.log(data). Then right click on the browser, choose "Inspect Element", then click on the Console tab when Firebug pops up. You run the Ajax call, and you should see a response pop up in the console. It should be green. Click on that, and it'll expand like a tree and show you the parts of the JSON response. Good luck.

Comment: You need to put the `console.log(data);` into your code. Once the code has run just bring up the console (F12) and it will be there in the tree view described by @Jemaclus. Alternatively you could put a breakpoint in your JS code after the data has been returned.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `console.log( yourarray );` You will be able to see the output in the browsers JavaScript console.

Answer (score 1):

Why not look at the object using the inspector built into your browser?  Chrome, Firefox, and newer versions of IE have inspectors that could help you without the need to write any code of your own.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the command `console.dir( object )` which will specifically give you a better dump to explore using a tree-system in FireFox and Chrome.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inspect the JSON that you are getting from third party before writing any of your code against it, go to http://jsonlint.com/ and enter the Url (plain without callback) and click Validate. It would validate and display the formatted JSON.

http://jsonlint.com/

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/iCallOfDutyFILMS/uploads?orderby=published&alt=json&max-results=1

Answer (score 0):

If your browser or environment has the right `JSON` object (e.g. Firefox), you can use [`JSON.stringify(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert the object to a string and use however you wish.